# Remove '/home' directory from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

People i got `'www.domain.com/home'`. I want delete from name '/home'. Just on url should left `'www.domain.com'`.

I tested .htaccess but this not works. I see server automatic delete 'index.html' from URL. Some rules works in my htaccess but the replacing a names in URL - not.

Somebody know how to delete '/home'? I just spent all morning to find solution, but nothing working...

Comment: can you just move the docroot to /home ?

Comment: Yeah i can ... but i thought to easy way. I need to made code to refresh page for Home. That is problem ;) But i will make some moving page...

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^home/?$ / [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Cool every link in Google say "Go search on google what is httpd.conf..." .. GOD SAKE...

Comment: If You mean "copy and paste" to ".htaccess" - No, this not working.

Comment: Did you enable .htaccess? Try putting some random text on top of the file and see if it generates 500 error?